# DJI Android-UXSDKDemo Failed to resolve com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.13.1

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I'm trying to load the Android-UXSDKDemo sample project but I got an error  "Failed to resolve: com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.13.1". I'm using Android Studio 4.0.1.
The strange things is that I have implementation 'com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.13' in my gradle so I don't why it complains for "Failed to resolve: com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.13.1". Any idea what is wrong?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            // On x86 devices that run Android API 23 or above, if the application is targeted with API 23 or
            // above, FFmpeg lib might lead to runtime crashes or warnings.
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJICommonJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJICSDKCommon.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIUpgradeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIUpgradeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIWaypointV2Core.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libAMapSDK_MAP_v6_9_2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIMOP.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.13', {
        /**
         * Uncomment the "library-anti-distortion" if your app does not need Anti Distortion for Mavic 2 Pro and Mavic 2 Zoom.
         * Uncomment the "fly-safe-database" if you need database for release, or we will download it when DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp
         * is called.
         * Both will greatly reducing the size of the APK.
         */
        exclude module: 'library-anti-distortion'
        //exclude module: 'fly-safe-database'
    })
    compileOnly 'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.13'
    implementation 'com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.13'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'


    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

// Please uncomment the following code if you use your own sdk version.
apply from : "https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/71a7d383e71a4fb8887a310eb746b47f/msdk/Android-CommonConfig/config_sample_all.gradle"
apply from : "https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/71a7d383e71a4fb8887a310eb746b47f/msdk/Android-CommonConfig/config_sample_dependencies_uxsdk.gradle"
```

My build.gradle(Module:app) is the original from https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-UXSDKDemo/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

Only the sdk was updated to 4.13.1, the ui sdk remained at 4.13.

It should read:

```
implementation('com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.13', {
    /**
     * Comment the "library-anti-distortion" if your app does need Anti Distortion for Mavic 2 Pro and Mavic 2 Zoom.
     * Comment the "fly-safe-database" if you do not need database for release, or we will download it when DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp
     * is called.
     * Both will greatly reducing the size of the APK.
     */
    //exclude module: 'library-anti-distortion'
    //exclude module: 'fly-safe-database'

    /**
     * Uncomment the following line to exclude amap from the app.
     * Note that Google Play Store does not allow APKs that include this library.
     */
    //exclude group: 'com.amap.api'
    //exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk'
})
compileOnly('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.13.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottom two lines are applying the latest version from DJI's servers. Remove these lines to fix the issue.

```
apply from : "https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/71a7d383e71a4fb8887a310eb746b47f/msdk/Android-CommonConfig/config_sample_all.gradle"
apply from : "https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/71a7d383e71a4fb8887a310eb746b47f/msdk/Android-CommonConfig/config_sample_dependencies_uxsdk.gradle"
```